# intervention image response in wrong orientation when image is saved on s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-8, orientation, intervention

I saved images on s3 (portrait). Now if I response them on page with intervention image, I see them in landscape orientation.
The same thing does not happen if I response them with `Storage::response()` function (I need to use intervention image to resize them).
So I thought to save locally a thumbnail of the image, and this is what I tried without success:

1. saved a copy in local storage, opened it, orientate it and save it
   again: NOT WORKING;
2. opened from s3, call the function setFileInfoFromPath, orientate it and save it again: NOT WORKING

This is the code I used for the first shot:

```
$localThumbPath = storage_path("app/tmp/thumb_{$id}.{$ext}");

// STORAGE IS S3
$img = Image::make(Storage::get("folder/{$id}.{$ext}"));
$img->save($localThumbPath);

$img = Image::make($localThumbPath)->orientate()->resize(100, 150, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$img->save($localThumbPath);

$s3 = Storage::disk('s3'); // maybe useless
$filePath = "/folder/thumb_{$id}." . $ext;
$s3->put($filePath, (string)$img->encode(), 'public-read');
```